# How to get rid of code duplication for Minimal API's

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

I am trying to learn to effectively use Minimal API's. How can I reduce duplicate codes, how to create base Endpoint class and do the most job there?

Especially, how to use Mediatr from a static reference and not put in every methods parameter?

My endpoint:

```
public static class ArticleEndpoints
{
    public static void MapArticleEndpoints(this WebApplication app)
    {
        var articles = app.MapGroup("Articles");

        articles.MapPost(nameof(CreateAsync), CreateAsync)
            .AddEndpointFilter<ValidationFilter<CreateArticleCommand>>()
            .WithName(nameof(CreateAsync))
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status201Created, typeof(Guid))
            .ProducesValidationProblem()
            .WithOpenApi();

        articles.MapPut(nameof(AddTagToArticleAsync), AddTagToArticleAsync)
            .AddEndpointFilter<ValidationFilter<AddTagToArticleCommand>>()
            .WithName(nameof(AddTagToArticleAsync))
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status200OK, typeof(ArticleGetByIdDto))
            .ProducesValidationProblem()
            .WithOpenApi();

        articles.MapGet(nameof(GetAllAsync), GetAllAsync)
            .WithName(nameof(GetAllAsync))
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status200OK, typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<ArticleGetAllDto>))
            .WithOpenApi();

        articles.MapGet(nameof(GetByIdAsync), GetByIdAsync)
            .WithName(nameof(GetByIdAsync))
            .Produces(StatusCodes.Status200OK, typeof(TagGetByIdDto))
            .WithOpenApi();
    }

    public static async Task<IResult> CreateAsync([FromBody] CreateArticleCommand command, IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var id = await mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);
        return Results.Created(nameof(CreateAsync), new { id });
    }

    public static async Task<IResult> AddTagToArticleAsync([FromBody] AddTagToArticleCommand command, IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);
        return Results.Ok(result);
    }

    public static async Task<IResult> GetAllAsync(IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await mediator.Send(new GetAllArticlesQuery(), cancellationToken);
        return Results.Ok(result);
    }

    public static async Task<IResult> GetByIdAsync([FromBody] GetArticleByIdIncludeTagsQuery query, IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await mediator.Send(query, cancellationToken);
        return Results.Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"and not put in every constructor"_ - what constructor are you talking about?

Comment: Also I don't see much code duplication here, at least worth trying to refactor it out.

Comment: _"Especially, how to use Mediatr from a static reference and not put in every constructor?"_ - there is no static reference for Mediatr - it is injected via DI and I bet it uses scoped dependencies.

Comment: If you want to remove duplication for different `Map{EntityName}Endpoints` - it potentially can be done with some generic trickery - but for concrete one I will need to see full [mre].

Comment: sorry for confusing, I mean not put in every methods parameter. Call it like a Mediator.Send(..) which we can while using controllers

Comment: In short - you can't, at length - I would argue you should not cause it not worth the hustle (you will need some dynamic function building)

Comment: This [blog post](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/generating-bogus-http-endpoints-with-aspnet-core-minimal-apis) might be similar to what you need. It talks about creating basic CRUD endpoints for an entity.

Answer (score 2):

You can add metadata directly to the group instead of to each endpoint to avoid repetition. You can also write a custom `WithMethodName` extension method for `IEndpointConventionBuilder` and apply it to the entire group to avoid all with `WithName` calls.

If the response types are really what the `Produces` methods claim they are, you can use [TypedResults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/responses?view=aspnetcore-7.0#typedresults-vs-results) to automatically populate the produces metadata.

If `IMediator` was a singleton, you could resolve it from the `WebApplication` once before mapping the endpoints, so you wouldn't have to include it as a parameter to every method. But since it's scoped, keeping `IMediator` as a parameter probably makes sense.

If you wanted to go even further, you could also use reflection to loop over all the methods in a class and map them to their method name.

P.S. While it may work, I don't recommend accepting request bodies as part of a GET request even if the backend just retrieves data without updating the database. A POST endpoint is more common. A GET makes sense if `GetArticleByIdIncludeTagsQuery` can be encoded into the query string. You can [implement TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#tryparse) to convert the string to the type you want in your method.

```cs
public static class ArticleEndpoints
{
    public static void MapArticleEndpoints(this WebApplication app)
    {
        var articles = app.MapGroup("Articles");
        articles.WithOpenApi();
        // WithMethodName is a custom extension method defined below.
        articles.WithMethodName();

        articles.MapGet(nameof(GetAllAsync), GetAllAsync);
        articles.MapPost(nameof(GetByIdAsync), GetByIdAsync);

        // Use an empty prefix, since we're only using this group for metadata,
        var validated = articles.MapGroup("");

        // With new API, the following line could be rewritten as just "validated.ProducesValidationProblem();"
        // Thumbs up https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43985 to support making ProducesValidationProblem() work on groups.
        validated.WithMetadata(new ProducesResponseTypeMetadata(
            400, typeof(HttpValidationProblemDetails),
            new[] { "application/problem+json" }));

        validated.MapPost(nameof(CreateAsync), CreateAsync)
            .AddEndpointFilter<ValidationFilter<CreateArticleCommand>>();
        validated.MapPut(nameof(AddTagToArticleAsync), AddTagToArticleAsync)
            .AddEndpointFilter<ValidationFilter<AddTagToArticleCommand>>();
    }

    public static async Task<Created<Guid>> CreateAsync([FromBody] CreateArticleCommand command, IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var id = await mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);
        return TypedResults.Created(nameof(CreateAsync), new { id });
    }

    public static async Task<Ok<ArticleGetByIdDto>> AddTagToArticleAsync([FromBody] AddTagToArticleCommand command, IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);
        return TypedResults.Ok(result);
    }

    public static async Task<Ok<IReadOnlyCollection<ArticleGetAllDto>>> GetAllAsync(IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await mediator.Send(new GetAllArticlesQuery(), cancellationToken);
        return TypedResults.Ok(result);
    }

    public static async Task<OK<TagGetByIdDto>> GetByIdAsync([FromBody] GetArticleByIdIncludeTagsQuery query, IMediator mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await mediator.Send(query, cancellationToken);
        return TypedResults.Ok(result);
    }

    public static IEndpointConventionBuilder WithMethodName(this IEndpointConventionBuilder conventionBuilder)
    {
        conventionBuilder.Add(endpointBuilder =>
        {
            var methodInfo = endpointBuilder.Metadata.OfType<MethodInfo>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (methodInfo?.Name is string methodName)
            {
                endpointBuilder.Metadata.Add(new EndpointNameMetadata(methodName));
                endpointBuilder.Metadata.Add(new RouteNameMetadata(methodName));
            }
        });

        return conventionBuilder;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't tell if it worked with a previous .NET version, but `app.MapGroup("...").ProducesValidationProblem()` is not valid for .NET 7 at least.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @PeterWurzinger. I forgot that unlike most similar extension methods that target any `IEndpointConventionBuilder`, the "Produces" methods specifically on target `RouteHandlerBuilder`. I filed an issue to correct that at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43985. Please give it a thumbs up if you would like more of these methods to work with groups. For now, I'll update my answer to use the workaround of calling `.WithMetadata(new ProducesResponseTypeMetadata(statusCode, typeof(HttpValidationProblemDetails), new[] { "application/problem+json" }));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ArticleEndpoints
{
    public static void MapArticleEndpoints(this WebApplication app)
    {
        var articles = app.MapGroup("Articles");

        app.MapPost("/api/createarticle", [Authorize] async (CreateArticleCommand command, [FromServices] IMediator _mediator) =>
            {
                return await _mediator.Send(command);
            })
            .AddEndpointFilter<ValidationFilter<CreateArticleCommand>>()
            .Produces(201)
            .ProducesValidationProblem()
    }
}
```

Instead of making two separate methods, you can simply put the MediatR call inside the Minimal API method, as I have shown above.

Since we are defining the return type inside the Command/Query, you don't have to mention it again in the route. However, you can define a custom status code with `.Produce()`

Also, `.WithOpenApi()` is not needed here if you have configured swagger in your Program.cs file.

As shown above, you can completely remove `GetByIdAsync`, `GetAllAsync`, `AddTagToArticleAsync`, and `CreateAsync` methods, and only keep everything in the minimal API route.